# Parse value from json object with json path

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

Given example

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
}
```

From `$.phoneNumbers[0].type` I can parse `["iPhone"]`
But I only wants `iPhone` as in string value. And if I try `$.phoneNumbers[0].type[0]` it returns `i`. And if I use the result in js like `result[0]` it returns `[`. At this point I do not know what to do, any help is welcome. I'm really new at this.

Comment: What is the helper you're using? `$.phoneNumbers[:1].type` doesn't look like valid JS

Comment: `phoneNumbers[0].type`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hi, I was trying to use JSONPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You are doing it right, except that you should use `[0]` not `[:1]`

JSONpath, for some reason, always outputs an object or array on the screen display.

When you actually use this syntax in Javascript, you will get a plain string, `"iPhone"`, not an array `["iPhone"]`.

Here is a comparison of what you get:

#### JSONPath

[image]

#### Doing it in real Javascript

```js
const $ = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
}
console.log($.phoneNumbers[0].type)
```